# Interactive, read-only Jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have a notebook that given input from ipywidget sliders, does some calculations and generates a graph. Is there a way I can create a "read-only" version of this interactive notebook, essentially one in which the user can interact through the sliders but nothing else (like code entry)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you export the notebook to HTML, it will be a HTML representation of the notebook that isn't editable, and `ipywidgets` supports export to HTML. For example: http://jupyter.org/widgets

Comment: Hi Louise! Would you mind being a bit more explicit? I have been trying as well to get an HTML notebook with interactive widgets (I have some dropdown menus where users should be able to select values and see different results displayed). So far I have not been successful...
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334338/jupyter-embed-live-interactive-widgets

Comment: I just tried this export of `.ipynb` to HTML, and all of the code cells get expanded (whereas I'd want them folded, using the Codefolding nbextension), I don't see any ipywidgets rendered anywhere, nor do I see any plots (matplotlib or plotly).